# Can't Translate Extension Method Into Store Expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1, extension-methods

I have an extension method as follows:

```
public static bool SatisfiesSomeCondition(this Post post, SomeObj someObj)
{
   return post.SomeObjId == someObj.SomeObjId;
}
```

And i'm trying to use it like this:

```
var query = ctx.Posts.Where(p => p.SatisfiesSomeCondition(someObj)).ToList();
```

But i get the error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean SatisfiesSomeCondition(xx.xx.xx.Post, xx.xx.xx.SomeObj)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

If i change the query to:

```
var query = ctx.Posts.Where(p => p.SomeObjId == someObj.SomeObjId).ToList();
```

Which is identical to the method.

It works fine, and executes the expected T-SQL.

Why doesn't my first query work? It's a static method, can't it figure out how to create the expression tree? (e.g a WHERE filter). Surely i don't have to materialize the query first? (which means the records i don't want come back over the wire, and i'm doing paging/ordering here, so that's not an option).

Of course, i can just go with what works (e.g the above), but the method `SatisfiesSomeCondition` is an existing method used across the domain and i want to re-use that functionality, not duplicate it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LINQ to Entities engine has no way of knowing what your static method does.
LINQ queries can only be translated from expression trees.

Comment: Fair enough. What do you suggest? Duplicating functionality? Is there any way i can use that method without duping it?

Comment: Unfortunately, not that I know of.  You could make a function that returns an `Expression<Func<Post, bool>>`, but you won't be able to compose it.

Comment: Yep, i was in the middle of trying to make the method return the predicate, but also my original query had an OR statement, which makes it difficult. e.g: `Where(x => x.Something || x.SatisfiesSomeCondition(someObj))`. So i would have to incorporate the entire `Where` condition into the method. Will look into predicatebuilder.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work with PredicateBuilder either, same problem. Accepting this answer. For the record, i ended up duping the filtering logic.

Answer (score 4):

Change it to:

```
public static IQueryable<Post> SatisfiesSomeCondition(this IQueryable<Post> query, SomeObj someObj)
{
   int id = someObj.SomeObjId;
   return query.Where(post => post.SomeObjId == id);
}
```

and use it like:

```
var query = ctx.Posts.SatisfiesSomeCondition(someObj)).ToList();
```

This way it should work. You can combine multiple `Where` conditions in single query so it should offer you at least basic reusablity.

Comment: but then i can't use an OR operator, can i? See my comment to SLaks answer.

Comment: No you cannot use or operation. Extension methods will not offer you extensibility for combining expressions in single condition.